# Hiding a div when mouse is clicked on any part of the page, other than the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Currently, I have a button called 'Comment' that when clicked slides down a comment box. I want the comment box to hide whenever the user clicks on any area of the page other than the comment box itself.

Currently, with my code the button just disappears when it is clicked. Could anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Ruby ERB:

```
<% @entry.each do |e| %>
<div class="entry">
<p><%= e.entry %></p>
<small>Posted by <%= e.author %> at <%= e.created_at.strftime("%I:%M%p %m/%d/%Y") %></small>
<% if e.comments.nil? %>
    <p>No Comments</p>
<% else %>
    <% e.comments.each do |c| %>
    <div class="comment">
    <blockquote><strong><%= c.author %></strong> writes:<%= c.comment %></blockquote>
    </div>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
<div class="comments">
<a href="#" data-comment="<%= e.id %>" class="newcommentbutton">Comment</a>
<div class="newcomment" id="comment<%= e.id %>">
<%= form_for @comment, :url => entry_comments_path(e, @comment) do |f| %>
<ol>
<li><%= f.label :author %>
<%= f.text_field :author %></li>
<li><%= f.label :comment %>
<%= f.text_area :comment %></li>
<%= f.submit %>
</ol>
<% end %>
</div>
</div>
    </div>
<hr />
<% end %>
<%= button_to "Write A Message", new_entry_path, :method => :get %>
```

Javascript:

```
// Place your application-specific JavaScript functions and classes here
// This file is automatically included by javascript_include_tag :defaults
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('.newcommentbutton').click(function()
{
    var button = $(this);
    var comment = button.attr('data-comment');
    button.hide();
    $('#comment' + comment).slideDown('fast', function() {
        $('#comment' + comment + ' input[type=text]').focus();  
    });

});
$('.newcomment').click(function(event)
{
    event.stopPropagation();
});
$('body').click(function()
{
    $('.newcomment').hide();
});


});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your new comment buttons *also* needs to [stop propagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/), like this:

```
$('.newcommentbutton').click(function(e) {
    var button = $(this);
    var comment = button.attr('data-comment');
    button.hide();
    $('#comment' + comment).slideDown('fast', function() {
        $('#comment' + comment + ' input[type=text]').focus();  
    });
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

You have the right idea, just remember that `.newcommentbutton` is *also* in `<body>` so it's opening the comment form, then the click bubbles up and closes it.

Comment: You are faster typer than me ;-), but I can at least give an advice to the asker: in such cases try to debug which events are called in what order. Place some "alerts" or "window.dump" messages, and the errors similar to this one may become obvious.

Comment: Thanks heaps. I'm fairly new to the idea of event propagation but i see why i need to stop it on both. Cheers!

Comment: console does not exist in "plain" browsers, at least not in Firefox. It's added by "firebug" plugin. I have been hit hard by this problem after I put a code with console.debug() calls into production: resolution "works for me" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a div like that:

```
<div id="comment"...>
```

You can put the focus on it, when you show it:

```
document.getElementById('comment').focus();
```

You need to set a `tabindex` attribute to your `DIV` to make the focus work:

```
<div id="comment" tabindex="99"...>
```

Then you set an onblur on it, and it will disappear, when the user click anywhere on the page:

```
document.getElementById('comment').onblur = function(){
  this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
};
```